# Snap Launching on Unity 7 But Not Unity 8

Tags: command-line, unity, snap, unity8

I currently have a snap working and running on Unity 7 (16.04 and 16.10).

However when I try to run it on Unity 8 (16.10) I get hit with this:

```
...    
GMT QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted (core dumped)
```

([See full log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23420077/))

Has anyone come across this? If so, what does it mean and how do I resolve this and get my Snap working on Unity 8?

From all the searching I've done they all mention about a `HEADLESS Server` which isn't the case because I'm trying to launch a snap **not** a server.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What GPU do you have/drivers? Note: Unity 8 is currently *not* a "consumer ready", or even stable, Desktop Environment.

Comment: @PatrickNegus 
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09).  3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] [10de:1341] (rev a2)

Comment: Are you using proprietary nVidia drivers?